# Get all Images in Gallery 

Tags: android, gridview, galleryview

I am developing an application in which I want that When a user clicks on button "select image", it should be able to view all images of drawable folder in gallaryview or gridview. How can I do this? and after clicking on the image from grid or gallery view, I have to just fatch that image path and store into a variable. I also want that when I go back to the previous page I have all my data with the image path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class GetImageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

    private String selectedImagePath;
    private ImageView img;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am new in android. So can you explain me the code? Should I have to put Images in image folder?

Comment: No no. Not in any folders. This will directly take you to your phone gallery and you would be shown all the images that are there in your phone. And when you select any image from it, it gets displayed in the ImageView.

Comment: Actually I just take some of it's information. Not tried whole code.