# pick image from gallery and convert into byte data how?

Tags: android, image, gallery

I need to pick an image from gallery and then convert it into byte data. I know how to pick image from gallery. Also I know how to convert image to byte data. But problem is i convert image that are in drawable but now I need to pick it from gallery and convert it to byte code. Any help 
THanks
In onClick function I am using this code to pick image from gallery

```
Intent image = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        image.setType("Image/*");
        startActivityForResult(image, 0);
```

And I have used following code to convert image that is in drawable to byte data.

```
 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
       data = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
       bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40 , data);
     bitmapdata = data.toByteArray();
```

Now how would i convert image from gallery to byte data.
Thanks

Comment: i didn't get any direction how would i do that. I can paste code of convert into byte data to an image that is in drawable. should i paste?

Comment: You said: "*I know how to pick image from gallery.*" What is your method for doing this?

Comment: from drawable it is easy just i have to do  R.drawable.name of image

Comment: This one shows you how to get the path of the gallerty image in your storage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123883/get-all-images-in-gallery

Comment: @Tamir In this example. can i use selectedImagePath in place of R.drawable.ic_launcher for conversion

Comment: you need to read it from storage like in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209842/read-write-file-to-internal-private-storage

Comment: @Tamir thanks but i m confused. it will be really helpful if u paste the code related to my problem as an answer

Comment: k, this one should be more helpful: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/SaveBitmaptoandloadfromExternalStorage.htm

Answer (score 2):

In `onActivityResult` you will receive the `Uri` to your selected image like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null){
       Uri imageUri = data.getData();
       //....
    }
}
```

Then to retrieve it from the `MediaStore` you should use :

```
 Bitmap bitmap =
      MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
```

after that, you should process the `Bitmap` like you do it now.

Comment: the code to retrieve will be in the onActivityResult method?? If i use this outside this method i get the error  ::::     - Default constructor cannot handle exception type FileNotFoundException thrown by implicit super 
  constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
 - Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. 
  Must define an explicit constructor